# php how to duplicate values in array (multidimensional)

Tags: php, mysql

My db table is:

```
author               book                    repeat
------               ----                    ------
Paulo Coelho         the alchemist           2
Adam Smith           The Wealth of Nations   1
```

I fetch data from db with the following php code:

```
...
$books_array[]= array(
       'author'=> $row['author'],
       'book'=> $row['book'],
);
```

But I don't know how to repeat the values according to my repeat value. How can I obtain the following array?

```
 array
     [0] => Array
        (
          [author] => Coelho
          [book] => The Alchemist
        )

     [1] => Array
        (
          [author] => Coelho
          [book] => The Alchemist
        )

     [2] => Array
        (
          [author] => Smith
          [book] => The Wealth of Nations
        )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oups! Just thought about! That was easy!

Just added

```
 for( $i= 0 ; $i <= $row['repeat'] ; $i++ ){
   $books_array[]= array(
   'author'=> $row['author'],
   'book'=> $row['book'],
    );
 };
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone else :) !!!!